# Как объединить два предложения логически и убрать лишние "я"?

Tags: стилистика

Я снова подсветил палочкой руку, и вздохнул с облегчением—кости срослись, но рука все ещё должна была оставаться неподвижной, и я занялся перевязкой. Потом я опустился на колени, погрузил губы в прозрачную воду и глотнул. Вода обожгла мне горло и рот, но она была вкусной и немного напоминала нарзан. Мне захотелось искупаться. Я немного прошёл по голубовато-зеленому берегу, разделся и зашёл в воду; все моё тело обдало холодом, но я быстро привык к нему—недаром Мари и Валентин закаляли меня и приучили к ныряниям в прорубь.

Comment: Какие два предложения вы хотите объединить?

Comment: Тире от слов отделятся пробелами с обеих сторон.

Answer (score 1):

Я снова подсветил палочкой руку, вздохнул с облегчением — кости срослись, но рука все ещё должна была оставаться неподвижной — и занялся перевязкой. Потом  опустился на колени, погрузил губы в прозрачную воду и глотнул. Вода обожгла  горло и рот, но  была вкусной и немного напоминала нарзан. Захотелось искупаться. Немного прошёл по голубовато-зеленому берегу, разделся и зашёл в воду; все  тело обдало холодом, но я быстро привык к нему — недаром Мари и Валентин закаляли меня и приучили к ныряниям в прорубь.

Comment: "Немного прошёл" — как-то не по-русски. Может, "прошелся"? И здесь, после двух предложенй без *я*, надо бы это *я* вернуть: "Я немного прошёлся по голубовато-зеленому берегу". "Привык к нему" — тоже не очень. Может, "Перестал его ощущать"?

Answer (score 0):

Убрать "я" можно в начале второго предложения. Лишним кажется местоимение "она", относящееся к воде.